# Retrieving Data Asynchronously from my API

Tags: android

I'm rewriting some of my code after years of stepping away from it, and wanted to ask the community for a push in the right direction from a more modern architecture perspective (if one is needed).

--

One of the things my app does is send JSON data (maybe about 15-20 key-value pairs in total) upon clicking a button in the app.

I wrote the code to use `Volley` inside an `AsyncTask` to interact with my API.

I created a progress bar that would basically block the UI with a loading spinner until the data sent out and then got a confirm back from the API.
When that is done, it would dismiss and the user could carry on, but in a few rare cases some of my users complain the data is slow and the progress bar takes a while to go away (a full 5-10 minutes, which is interesting) or just never goes away at all.

I believe I erred here in creating the spinner, so I will do away with that and have it run in the background.

I found myself more confused than ever at the seemingly various approaches and frameworks out there for interacting with APIs that weren't as available years ago, so wanted to ask here in hopes of getting a more unified / community-based response.

**My Question**

Is it still a modern/ideal/commonly found approach to

1. Create a class that `extends AsyncTask<type here>`
2. Add your your `onPreExecute`, `doInBackground(String... params)`, `onPostExecute`, declarations and code
3. Use code like this to interact with your API using Volley:

My old code is below, and unfortunately I've wrote many tasks like this (practically every case of where I need to make an API call has this large bloated file that follows the format below).

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {   
     RequestQueue mmRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);              


 StringRequest mmyReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, "ENDPOINT HERE", new Response.Listener<String>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String rawResponse) {        

                        JSONObject response = null;
                        try {
                              response = new JSONObject(rawResponse);
                              //do stuff with response here..
                            }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            //logging code here
                        }                   
                    }
                }, 
                new Response.ErrorListener() 
                {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         //handle my stuff here
                   }
                }                       
     ) 
     {
         @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
            {  
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();                
                     //put my params here, for example:
                    params.put("helloworld", val1); 
                    params.put("helloworld2", val2);                                                
                    return params;  
            }
     };
     mmRequestQueue.add(mmyReq);

      try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); //not sure why this is even here anymore, I can't recall if this was intentional or not, maybe it was to show the progress bar which I won't be using anymore anyway?
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: That Volley request is already asynchronous. You don't need the `AsyncTask` to queue it. You could use one to parse the response, though, as `onResponse()` is called on the main thread, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, but in almost all cases (except a fire-and-forget style one) wouldn't I always want to see what the response was, thus almost always need it in AsyncTask? Maybe I'm missing something. thanks!

Comment: Removing the outer `AsyncTask` does not preclude you from getting the results. They will be delivered to `onResponse()` like always. My point was that Volley is already asynchronous, so you don't need an `AsyncTask` just to queue the `StringRequest`. You can think of it like Volley already having its own `AsyncTask` in its queue. You starting up your own `AsyncTask` just to hand something to Volley's asynchronous queue is pointless. I would guess that you had `Thread.sleep()` there specifically because the queuing is asynchronous. The `add()` call returns immediately.